# Send email everytime php generates a fatal error

Tags: fatal-error, php

How would I write a PHP code that would send me an email everytime I get a

`Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14373306 bytes) in  on line <b>443</b><br />`.

I'm running a script wherein a user has this URL and it will be process by my code, but the problem here is that sometimes it results to a `Fatal error Allowed memory size exhausted`. I want an email to be sent to me that tells me that there has this error at the same time what URL is causing that error.

So the logic is something like this.

```
if( error == "Fatal Error Allowed memory Size" ) {
 mail("myemail@email.com", "Fatal Error - URL: http://google.com");
}
```

I hope the instruction is pretty clear. Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thanks! :-)

Comment: that's not going to work. you'd be trying to run MORE php code at the very time that PHP is barfing bits all of your server. it's dying, and you'd be going "wait, do this <long job here> before you croak!". use an external logfile monitor and trap the messages there, independently of php

Comment: I do not think that you can catch the php fatal errors inside the php. As the name `fatal` process is killed. You should add this functionality to your http server (apache, lighttpd). If you can tell your server environment i can help you.

Comment: @TolgaAkyüz: My operating system is Linux. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MarcB: I wonder what would be a solution for this. Actually i'm running the script using a Cron Job so there's no way I would really know what URL was being use to cause the Fatal Error.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at using `register_shutdown_function()`. It can be used to execute on `E_ERROR`(fatal error)

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

function shutdown()
{
  if(!is_null($e = error_get_last()))
  {
    mail("myemail@email.com", "Fatal Error - ". var_export($e, true));
  }
}
```

I would however echo thoughts in the comments above that this is best handled using log monitoring.

Comment: I honestly don't know what a log monitoring is. Is that a software or a piece of PHP code? Any links on that one or something you suggest that would be best to monitor logs. Thanks! :)

Comment: There are any number of log monitoring/processing tools available.  You could also write a PHP script to parse the logs and do this for you as well.

Comment: I see. I will look on that. Thanks! As of now, I will test out your code above.

Comment: By the way, that code won't let me tell which URL caused the Fatal Error. Is there a way to know?

Comment: @ElsonSolano See my updated answer for a suggestion on how to access some variable in the shutdown function.  Keep in mind that variable value may or may not be available based on whether this variable assignment was directly related to your memory allocation problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Init following function inside your php file.

register_shutdown_function('mail_on_error'); //inside your php script

/** If  any file having any kind of fatal error, sln team will be notified when cron will
become fail : following is the name of handler and its type
E_ERROR: 1 | E_WARNING: 2 | E_PARSE: 4 | E_NOTICE: 8
*/

function mail_on_error() {
    global $objSettings;

    $error = error_get_last();
    //print_r($error);    

  if ($error['type'] == 1) {

        // update file path into db
        $objSettings->update_records($id=1,array('fatal_error' => json_encode($error)));

        $exception_in_file_path = __FILE__;
        fatal_error_structure($exception_in_file_path);

  }// end if

}// end mail_on_error

fatal_error_structure should be defined on some global location. like function.inc.php. This will send an email to registered user.


function fatal_error_structure($exception_in_file_path){

        $subject = "FATAL: Cron Daemon has failed";

    sln_send_mail(nl2br("Please check $exception_in_file_path, This cron having FATAL error."), 
        $subject, 'email@address.com',$name_reciever='', 'text/plain');

}// end fatal_error_structure

vKj
```